# Importing .android.gms.* partially fails in Android Studio

Tags: android, api

I am trying to add support for several Google Play Services for my application into Android Studio (1.0.2).  I've added  the API's through SDK manager, but I'm trouble with only ***some*** of the imports:

[image]

Can anyone explain why some of these imports are working while others do not?

Thank you,
Josh

Comment: Can you post the dependencies from your application's `build.gradle` file please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import the play services library into your project as a module

It can be found under /android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject